# how to authenticate o365 account and send email via graph API in Nodejs as backend service

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I can get the access token using https://login.microsoftonline.com/***/oauth2/v2.0/token But could not send email using Microsoft graph API in NodeJS

Comment: here's a sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-nodejs-tutorial/blob/main/2-Authorization/1-call-graph/README.md

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @Ravi , are you able to solve your issue ,or do you need any further help ?